# Middle element from a disjoint set of sorted intervals

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, numbers, set

> We want to find the middle element in the given intervals of numbers.
>
> Suppose we are given a set with 3 intervals which are { [1, 10], [20,
> 30], [35, 40] }. (The intervals are always disjoint).
>
> If we combine all intervals we get 25 numbers which are given below:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29,
> 30, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40
>
> The answer is the middle element which is the 13th element which is
> 22. So the answer is 22.
>
> But each of the intervals can be of range [1,1000000000]. Given the
> intervals you are to calculate the middle element.
>
> Is there any data structure or algorithm to code this ?
>
> Note : If there are 'n' number of elements and 'n' is even the answer
> can be the (n/2)th element.
>
> Example : if there are total four elements if we combine intervals
> then the 2nd element is the answer

Comment: Why not just iterate over the intervals with one pointer from the bottom and one from the top, keeping the sums of the number of elements as close as possible from both sides, then find the middle?

Comment: I can't do that. It will take a lot of time and I will get TLE.

Comment: It will take a long time? It's O(n), how could one do better without looking at all the intervals?

Comment: To take your example, we've got 10 on the left, 6 on the right, then 11 in the middle. We take 4 from the right side of the 11, which leaves us with 20-26, which is 7 elements. Divide in two and take three from either side, ending with 23 (22 seems wrong - since there are 27 elements, the middle is the 14th element).

Comment: By O(n), I meant that n is the number of intervals given.

Comment: Yes there are 27 elements. Thank you for pointing out. 
The number of intervals 'N' (say) can be (3/4)*(10^9) . So the number of intervals also is very large.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when we combine the intervals in your example we get 27 numbers and the middle element (median) is the 14th element which is 23.
As גלעד ברקן mentioned in the comment the fastest way to achieve what you want is O(n) where n is the number of intervals (n = 3 in your above example). Here's Python code with explanation

```
# I assume your intervals are list in a list
def findMedian(intervals):
   numberOfElements = 0

   for interval in intervals:
      numberOfElements += interval[1] - interval[0] + 1 # We count how many numbers are in each interval

   middleElementPosition = numberOfElements//2 
   median = 0

   # At this point we know how many numbers are in the intervals and the position of the middle number
   # So we go and find the middle number 
   for i in range(len(intervals)):
      if middleElementPosition > (intervals[i][1] - intervals[i][0] + 1):
         middleElementPosition -= (intervals[i][1] - intervals[i][0] + 1)
      else:
         median = intervals[i][0] + middleElementPosition
         break # once we find median we leave loop

    return median
```

Note that we are mainly working with the number of elements, not the elements themselves. All that matters is the number of intervals.